# Change the swipe-up options on the Lollipop lockscreen?

Tags: lock-screens, 5.1-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow

I went back to Lollipop from Marshmallow recently and I miss having the ability to swipe up from the left of the screen to get right into Google Now voice search. Is there any way to change (with root perhaps?) the phone shortcut to the voice search shortcut on Lollipop?

Comment: Your Android device name? I'm not sure whether stock Android has this feature, but you can configure the lock screen in custom ROMs.

Comment: HTC One M8, stock ROM, rooted.